# Powerapps: Populating a form based on submission of a form on a seperate page

Tags: liquid, powerapps, powerapps-portal

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to create a form that populates a certain field based on another parent form on PowerApps (portals/pages). However, I'm facing some issues and would appreciate any help or guidance that you can provide.

Essentially, what I'm trying to achieve is that when a user fills out a parent form, it should populate a certain field on a child form. This field should be pre-populated with data from the parent form.

I would like to try accomplish this through the powerapps platform out of the box but to my understanding the best way to do this is with liquid code? But I can't seem to get any code I write to work. If anyone could give me any pointers as to how I would go about doing this or even point me in the direction of some helpful resources it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Liquid code that takes the form submission, puts it in a hidden html div and then gets taken by some javascript and placed in the child form